# Best practice for displaying a tabsetPanel with a dynamic amount of tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I am still in the process of finding my way into Shiny, and I've hit my next road block. Usually, when we have a `ui` object, we want to call one of the `fooOutput` functions after setting an attribute of output using the `renderFoo` functions.

When we create a `tabPanel`, we pass it a name and the output of one of the `fooOutput` functions, and we can then use this `tabPanel` by including it somewhere in the hierarchy of our app. Previously I did this using the `renderUI` function on my server and passing the output of that into `output`. Recent discussions have given me the impression that we really only want to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` if it really cannot be avoided because 1) it's "dirty", and 2) it increases the load on the server.

For my use case, let's say we're facing the following situation. We have a list of data frames which may include an arbitrary amount of data frames including zero. If I use `renderUI`, displaying this list in a `tabsetPanel` is more or less trivial:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- lapply(X=1:5, FUN=function(i) { data.frame(X=1:10, Y=rnorm(n=10)) })

  lapply(X=seq_along(data), FUN=function(i) {
    output[[paste0("table", i)]] <- renderTable(data[[i]])
  })

  output$tabsetPanel <- renderUI({
    do.call(tabsetPanel, {
      lapply(X=seq_along(data),
             FUN=function(i) {
               tabPanel(title=paste("Tab", i),
                        tableOutput(paste0("table", i)))
             })
    })
  })
}
```

... so that in our `ui` object we can just call `uiOutput("tabsetPanel")`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("tabsetPanel")
)
```

First, is the manner in which I display these tables needlessly convoluted? Is there a much more intuitive way of doing it? And then the more important question, how can I create a `tabsetPanel` from these tabPanels without resorting to `renderUI`?

Comment: `renderUI` is most useful when you have some reactivity going on, which you don't in this case.  You could build your data in the `global.r`, then run your `do.call` right on the UI script, within a `tagList`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out once I get the opportunity. Do you have a great example off the top of your head where using `renderUI` would be an appropriate solution to a problem?

Comment: One more thing, I think there was a miscommunication here. There is reactivity in such a sense that the data frames are generated from a file which is uploaded and then evaluated. Is this such a scenario where `renderUI` is a sensible solution?

Comment: Ah, yes that,s a different situation. If you're using `fileInput` to allow users to upload their own data, you'll need server side rendering like in your original example.  In that case i think `renderUI` is appropriate.  You need a large piece of UI, the whole tabset Panel, to update with new data.